# Alexa Skill Kit account linking accessToken field is not shown

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

I wonder about the `accessToken`, after account linking everything works well, but I have problems with the `accessToken`, it is not shown in the request generated. After account linking this is an example of what Alexa returns:

```
"user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.myuserid",
            "permissions": {
                "consentToken": "allMyConsentTOKENNNNNNN"
            }
        }
```

After linking my account Alexa tell me that the account was successfully linked.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

If you have configured *Account Linking* properly and is able to link your account, then `accessToken` will be there in every subsequent request from your skill.

Make sure that:

1. **Account Linking Config**: Are all your configurations in *Account Linking* tab correct. Check your `Access Token URI`, is it a valid one.
2. **Test using same account**: Test from the same developer account where the skill is enabled and linked.
3. **Check OAuth2 provider**: Are you using your own OAuth server? If yes, is it working as expected. Are there any configurations that you might have missed? Check your  `access_type`, set the value to `offline` if your application needs to refresh access tokens when the user is not present at the browser.
4. If you are testing from *Test Simulator* try refreshing the page or disable *Test* and re-enable it.

Comment: Hi and thanks, I am using [this project for the account linking](https://github.com/pdonaire1/alexa-skill-linked-account-twitter-middleware) and also I am using the Implicit Grant option in alexa not Auth Code Grant, I have to change it?